Squid denying access after IP change
I recently moved my proxmox host & (exposed) VMs to a new subnet, from 192.168.0.0/24 to 192.168.1.0/24. All went as expected EXCEPT squid which is denying access to the clients.
On the squid host, internet access is fine:
root@glue:/etc/squid# wget https://www.google.co.uk
--2024-07-15 09:49:58--  https://www.google.co.uk/
Resolving www.google.co.uk (www.google.co.uk)... 2a00:1450:4009:820::2003, 172.217.169.3
Connecting to www.google.co.uk (www.google.co.uk)|2a00:1450:4009:820::2003|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: 'index.html'

index.html                                              [ <=>                                                                                                              ]  19.63K  --.-KB/s    in 0.02s

2024-07-15 09:49:59 (1.20 MB/s) - 'index.html' saved [20102]

However routing requests via the proxy fails:
root@glue:~# export http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
root@glue:~# export https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:3128
root@glue:~# 
root@glue:~# wget --server-response https://www.google.co.uk
--2024-07-15 09:42:15--  https://www.google.co.uk/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:3128... connected.
Proxy tunneling failed: ForbiddenUnable to establish SSL connection.

Squid access.conf shows:
1721032843.653      0 127.0.0.1 TCP_DENIED/403 3810 CONNECT www.google.co.uk:443 - HIER_NONE/- text/html

The same error is reported for all 10.0.0.0/24 clients.
The squid.conf has no hard-coded IP addresses and a full reboot was applied after the address change. Squid.conf (excluding comments and blank lines):
acl SSL_ports port 443
http_access deny !Safe_ports
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports
http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager
include /etc/squid/conf.d/*.conf
http_access allow localnet
http_access deny all
http_port 3128
coredump_dir /var/spool/squid
refresh_pattern ^ftp:           1440    20%     10080
refresh_pattern ^gopher:        1440    0%      1440
refresh_pattern -i (/cgi-bin/|\?) 0     0%      0
refresh_pattern .               0       20%     4320

This host has interfaces 127.0.0.1, 10.0.0.1, 192.168.1.251. The ipv6 address is obtained via dhcp on the NIC also using 192.168.1.251 which is where the default route lives (ipv4 and ipv6).
What am I missing here?
update
This is weird. After failing for 30-40 minutes, access started working again for localhost with no intervention. Still failing on other hosts.

Maybe squid has used cached DNS names, which needed some time to refresh their IP.

Where did you define localnet?

What DNS names? There's none in the config. I didn't define localnet - squid does this out of the box based on the interfaces on the host.

@symcbean huh, strange. Couldn't find that in the documentation and never heard of it before. TIL! Thanks
